# ANDing tags together on the favorite tags list

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-watching

It would be useful to have the ability to favorite the intersection of two tags; that is, only highlight a post if it contains *both* of the specified tags.

Example : We have a tag [string](/questions/tagged/string) and a tag [java](/questions/tagged/java). If a user has good knowledge about strings in java, but neither about all java nor about all (languages) strings. So he would like to favorite them together only.

I know that a user can search questions with multiple tags but he will find lot of undesired questions with his ignored tags as well.

So **If user would be able to add intersection of two tags to his favorite tags** he would love to see questions with such tags highlighted like his other favorite tags

Favorite tags is a feature. Ignoring them is also a feature. But **favoring a tag like [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)* is an excellent extension of 'favorite tags' feature. I am talking about a similar extension of same (favorite tags) feature.**

Is it possible to AND tags together like this when favoriting them? Can that be added if not?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried to add two tags as `java string` to my favorite tags but got two independent tags `java` and `string` added

Comment: Read the post carefully; type the tags into the searchbox of the site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry I edited the question. I am just asking about favorite tags. Adding two tags(dependent on each other) to favorite tags

Answer (score -2):

### No, please.

Favorite tags are a more global feature, I think. All tags are equal in that space.

Introducing an `AND` operator would also probably require introducing an `OR` operator, maybe priority modifiers (parentheses) and much more complexity in the long run just to be backwards compatible with what we already have.

Comment: I don't think any of the things you listed are strictly necessary. If you want to OR tags together you add them separately, if you want to AND them you do some other new syntax, and more complex expressions can stay unsupported

Comment: @Michael, true, you start with `AND` only requiring some repetition and a single syntax change (maybe even parentheses), but how long before someone wants `OR` expressions within these `AND`s? It usually goes downhill from there.

Comment: I do not think or needed. Neither not(!) is needed because they are already facilitated by separation of favorite and ignore tags. But there is no phenomena for anding. And I think Anding is needed to users although it can be provided or not. And can you mention a case where a thing like "or" is needed as I have told a scenario that how "and" can be needed

Comment: @Sami, you and Michael are right in that supporting simple `AND` would be possible without breaking backwards compatibility. I'm only saying this involves repetition if you have lots of, say, couples with the same "main" tag (e.g. `java+string java+int java+bool java+etc.` to take a literal example). In this situation, people are tempted to demand `OR` expressions inside `AND` expressions (e.g. `java+(string|int|bool)`) because they already have them outside of `AND` expressions in the first place.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi :) You are right. But very sorry as again `java+(string|int|bool)` can be excused easily. As one could do `java+bool` and `java+etc` easily if anding would be provided. I confess there could be thousands of complexity cases. But see SO could simply facilitate only favorite and not the ignore tags but they have done it. So i think gradually things can be improved on priority/trade off basis. I am not saying SO must do or do it immediately. But it could provide one of great facilities to users just like ignore tags.